# The result of the method spreadsheetAddRow cannot be assigned because it does not return a value

Tags: coldfusion

I have the following code which appears completely fine but keeps throwing the error: "The result of the method spreadsheetAddRow cannot be assigned because it does not return a value" This error is occurring at the row where I add the header. Nothing seems out of place and extensive google searching hasn't helped find anyone that has had a similar error. Hope the community can help!

```
<cfset newSheet = spreadsheetNew('Need Approval')>
<cfset headerRow = spreadsheetAddRow(newSheet,'ContactID,FirstName,LastName,Organization,RegisterDate,Approve,Deny')>
<cfset i = 2>
<cfoutput query="getNotApproved">
<cfset newRow = spreadsheetAddRow(newSheet,'#ContactID#,#FirstName#,#LastName#,#Organization#,#RegisterDate#',#i#,1)>
<cfset addApprove = spreadsheetSetCellFormula(newSheet,"HYPERLINK(https://mysite/approvalStatus.cfm?sts=approved&cid=#ContactID#&udf=#getShowrooms.Showroom#,'Click here to Approve')",#i#,6)>
<cfset addDeny = spreadsheetSetCellFormula(newSheet,"HYPERLINK(https://mysite/approvalStatus.cfm?sts=deny&cid=#ContactID#&udf=#getShowrooms.Showroom#,'Click here to Deny')",#i#,7)>
<cfset i++>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: To clarify, take another look at [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-67ad.html). The description says *"**Returns**: Does not return a value.*". Notice the examples do not try and capture any result? So the error is because you are trying to capture a value that does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
<cfset headerRow = spreadsheetAddRow
(newSheet,'ContactID,FirstName,LastName,Organization,RegisterDate,Approve,Deny')>
```

to this:

```
<cfset spreadsheetAddRow
(newSheet,'ContactID,FirstName,LastName,Organization,RegisterDate,Approve,Deny')>
```

The

In other words, remove the variable headerRow.

Comment: Granted, sometimes error messages lie. However, this is one of those cases where the message tells you exactly what is wrong :)

Comment: Genius. Worked like a charm, thanks much for all your help!

Comment: @Leigh, yes as I reread the error message I feel quite stupid for not realizing it myself. I guess that's what happens when you try to code for 20 hours straight, start to go cross-eyed and things get a little fuzzy. :)

Comment: @SChaudry - Haha, yeah I know that feeling :)